# Confusion about overloaded function when there is an rvalue reference argument

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, move-semantics, rvalue

If there is an rvalue reference in a function overload, how to call to function?
Why not call the version of the rvalue reference?

```
void test(int& x) {
    cout << "int &x" << endl;
}

void test(const int &x) {
    cout << "const int &x" << endl;
}

void test(int&& x) {
    cout << "int &&x" << endl;
}

void test(const int&& x) {
    cout << "const int &&x" << endl;
}

int main() {
    int &&rr = 10;
    const int &&crr = 10;
    test(rr); // call to int &x, why not call to int &&x
    test(crr); // call to const int &x, why not call to const int &&x
}
```

In addition, why call to 'test' is ambiguous?

```
void test(int x) {
    cout << "int &x" << endl;
}



void test(const int&& x) {
    cout << "const int &&x" << endl;
}

int main() {
    int &&rr = 10;
    test(10); // call to 'test' is ambiguous
    test(move(rr));
}
```

Comment: Even given that, in your original question you ask why `test(rr);` makes a call to the `int&` overload, but there is no such function as `test(int&& x)`. Were all four functions supposed to be `test` instead of `increment`?

Comment: rr and crr are named variables, they are lvalues. Thus, int &x and const int &x are selected.

Comment: @Nathan Pierson ，Sorry,  it is supposed to be test

Comment: @273K So，if pass-by-references, the function call should be judged by considering the lvalue and rvalue